# Modify multidimensional array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I append items from a database to an array, like that (I need the 0 in front):

```
tmpArray = [0]
sql = "SELECT value FROM employees;"
c.execute(sql)
rows = c.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    tmpArray.append([row[0]])
```

Output is like that:

```
tmpArray = [0, ["xxx"], ["yyy"], ["zzz"]]
```

I need the Array surrounded by brackets like that:

```
tmpArray = [(0, ["xxx"], ["yyy"], ["zzz"])]
```

How can I achieve this or how can I modify the current array, so I get the result that I want? Thank you for helping. The script that I want to use needs the data exactly like that.

Comment: `tuple(xs)` will convert any list (or rather, iterable) `xs` to a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this:

```
tmpArray = [0, ["xxx"], ["yyy"], ["zzz"]]

tmpArray=[tuple(tmpArray)]
print(tmpArray)
```